# Motion of a pendulum equation in the George Simmons book on differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

I just can't understand the transition between this two formulas, why $dt$ becomes $T/4$. Can anybody help me with that?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGVEN.jpg)

Comment: As $\theta$ goes from $\alpha$ to $0$ where does $t$ go?

Comment: Also please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures cannot be searched and are inaccessible to those using screen readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because we have:

$1$ period=(time from $\alpha$ to $0)+$ (time from $0$ to $-\alpha)+$  (time from  $-\alpha$ to $0$)+ (time from $0$ to $\alpha)$

and, by symmetry:

$T=(1$ period)=$4($time from $\alpha$ to $0)$
so:
$$
\int _\alpha ^0 dt=T/4
$$

Comment: Thank you very much!!

Ok, i won't use pictures in this way, this was my first question!

Comment: You are welcome! For write formulas visit: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference.   And don't forget to accept if you like an answer.